# why url with slash gives 404 error on website?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want URL with slash `/` at the end.

On my website if I the enter URL with slash `/` at the end it is giving 404 error.

I modified `.htaccess` file with the below code. Still not working.

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.php/.+$ [L,NC,R=404]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ inner.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Slash at the end of _what_? Give a proper example URL. _"I modified .htaccess file with the below code."_ - and how are we supposed to tell what part(s) you modified, when we don't know the _original_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

This (last) rule unconditionally rewrites any *remaining* URLs (that do not contain a dot) to append a `.php` extension. However, if you include a trailing slash on the requested URL, eg. `/foo/`, then it will rewrite the request to `/foo/.php` (instead of `/foo.php`) which will result in a 404 and is most certainly the cause of your problem.

You need to exclude the (mandatory) trailing slash from the captured subpattern. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

(*Aside:* No need to backslash-escape literal dots when used inside a regex character class and the `NC` flag is superfluous here, since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not differentiate case anyway.)

However, you should really be testing that the target `.php` file exists before rewriting the request, otherwise you are going to get 404's triggered by `/requested-url.php`, rather than `/requested-url` (the URL that was actually requested). In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I tired it. It is working.  thank you.